# C++ macro - pass as "parameter" next word instead of in ()

Tags: c++, parameters, macros, c-preprocessor

This code:

```
#define DEREF(ptr) (*ptr)

MyClass *pClass = new MyClass;
DEREF(pClass).foo(); // equivalent of (*pClass).foo() or simply pClass->foo()
```

Can I configure the `#define` macro to accept the ptr parameter as the word that follows the macro instead of bracketed statement, so that I can do the following?:

```
DEREF pClass.foo();
```

Comment: Why use a macro for this?  What is wrong with `->`?

Comment: That's just an example, not very practical, but used to clearly illustrate my point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, C macros can only receive parameters inside brackets '()'

Answer (score 4):

> Can I configure the #define macro to accept the ptr parameter as the word that follows the macro

No. You can, however, write custom code preprocessor that will transform your code before passing it to C++ compiler. This is not really simple or practical but can be done. [moc](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html) in [qt 4](http://qt.nokia.com/) operates this way - scans for custom keywords and replaces them with C++ statements compiler can accept. This allows Qt 4 to implement its "signal/slot" mechanism.